# Equivalent Definitions of Countable Sets

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

$\newcommand{\naturalset}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\range}[1]{\operatorname{range}\left(#1\right)}$

I knew of two definitions of countable sets:

(1) A set $S$ is countable if and only if $S \approx \mathbb{N}$ (countably infinite) or $S \approx n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (finite).

(2) A set $S$ is countable if and only if there exists an injective function $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$.

I tried to prove if these two definitions are equivalent, and I am checking if my proof is correct.

First of all, we assume the following theorem without proof: Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Then either $A$ is finite (in the first sense) or $A \approx \mathbb{N}$.

The proof of the above theorem is a little complicated. It is on page 141 of book "classic set theory" by Derek Goldrei.

Proof:

First assume that $S$ is countable. Then either there exists some $n \in \naturalset$ such that $S \approx n$ or $S \approx \naturalset$. In either case, there exists a function $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ which is injective. Thus we conclude that coutability indicates existence of an injective function.

Next assume that there exists a function $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ which is injective. Then $f$ can be either surjective or not.

First assume that $f$ is surjective. Then $S \approx \naturalset$ and $S$ is countably infinite.

Next assume that $f$ is not surjective. Then $\range{f} \subseteq \naturalset$ and $\range{f} \neq \naturalset$. Then with the theorem stated above, either $\range{f}$ is finite or $\range{f} \approx \naturalset$.

First assume that $\range{f}$ is finite. In this case, there exists some $n_{0}$ such that $\range{f} \approx n_{0}$. Using the fact that $S \approx \range{f}$, we have $S \approx n_{0}$. Thus, $S$ is finite.

Now assume that $\range{f} \approx \naturalset$, again using the fact that $S \approx \range{f}$, we have $S \approx \naturalset$, and $S$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Assume $range(f)$ is not finite, why should be $range(f)\approx\mathbb{N}$? I mean it's exactly what you should demonstrate. I think you should build the bijection to get a correct proof. And here i would use induction

Comment: @NoSignals I mentioned a theorem before the proof, which indicates a subset of natural numbers is either finite or countably infinite. The proof of that theorem is a little complicated. It is on page 141 of book "classic set theory" by Derek Goldrei.

Comment: I completely missed that part. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you can quote the theorem you mentioned without proof. In that case, you are overcomplicating the (2) $\implies$ (1) direction.

Since $f : S \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective, we have $S \approx \operatorname{ran}(f)$. Since $\operatorname{ran}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, by your theorem we have $\operatorname{ran}(f) \cong n$ for some $n$ or $\operatorname{ran}(f) \cong \mathbb{N}$. By the transitivity of $\approx$, $S \approx n$ or $S \approx \mathbb{N}$.